# Multiple file upload with progress bar for each file drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, jquery-file-upload

So i have implemented a dreg and drop upload functionality which works perfectly well. I have implemented a progress bar to show upload progress of the files. my problem is I want to show a progress bar for each file uploaded. but there is no way of updating the progress for each file.

My front end.

```
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
 <progress></progress>
```

Javascript

```
function handleDragOver(event) {
           event.stopPropagation();
           event.preventDefault();
           var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
           dropZone.innerHTML = "Drop now";
 }

   function handleDnDFileSelect(event) {
           event.stopPropagation();
           event.preventDefault();

           /* Read the list of all the selected files. */
           files = event.dataTransfer.files;

           /* Consolidate the output element. */
           var form = document.getElementById('form1');
           var nm2="";
           var data = new FormData(form);
           for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {



               data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);

           }
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/WebServices/uploadservice.asmx/uploadfile",
               xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                   var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                   if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists

                       myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                   }
                   return myXhr;
               },
               data: data,
               cache: false,
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,
               success: function (res) {
                   //  $("#uploadedfiles").append(res);

               },
               error: function (err) {
               }
           });

       function progressHandlingFunction(e){
           if (e.lengthComputable) {


               $('progress').attr({ value: e.loaded, max: e.total });
               count++;
           }
       }
       }
           if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {

        var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
        dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
        dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleDnDFileSelect, false);

    }
    else {
        alert('Sorry! this browser does not support HTML5 File APIs.');
    }
```

The webservice that saves the file

```
    public string uploadfile()
    {
        string savedfile = "";
        try
        {
            HttpFileCollection fileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

            for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpPostedFile upload = fileCollection[i];
                    int f = fileCollection[i].ContentLength;
                    string filename = "/ProductImages/" + fileCollection[i].FileName;
                    upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filename));
                    savedfile = fileCollection[i].FileName + "<br/>";
                }
                catch
                {
                }

            }
            return savedfile;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
```

The total progress for the upload is being shown correctly. I tried different methods to show individulal file progress. such as dynamically creating the progress bar in the for loop and making a separate call to the webservice for each file rather than making the call together for all files  but this does not work as the xmlhttprequest always works asynchronously. Any solutions

Comment: You can show progress bar for each ajax submission not for individual files.

Comment: even that doesnt work because i put the ajax call in the for loop. and the progress is updated partially only as the calls are asynchronous and it starts updating the progress of the next call and abandons the current one